# Get process occupying a port in Solaris 10 (alternative for pfiles)

Tags: unix, process, solaris, port

I am currently using pfiles to get the process occupying certain port in Solaris10,
but it causes problem when run parallely.

problem is pfiles  can't be run parallely for the same pid.
the second one will return with error message.
pfiles: process is traced :

Is there any alternative to pfiles to get the process occupying a port in Solaris.
OR any information on OS API's to get port/process information on Solaris could help.

Comment: Why do you need to run multiple pfiles in parallel ?

Comment: problem is my application uses pfiles to analyze occupied ports..meantime if pfiles is run manually or by some other application..or even multiple instances of my application it fails.

Comment: If it fails, just have your application waiting for a couple of seconds and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use some lock mechanism to avoid this.

Alternatively, you might install lsof from a freeware repository and see if it supports concurrency (I think it does).

I just tested Solaris 11 Express pfiles and it doesn't seem to exhibit this issue.